# Disable data migrations in Django when creating test database

Tags: django, migration, automated-tests

I have an app with a fair number of migrations including data migrations to set foreign keys on some models.

When I try to run tests.py, it fails because the data migration is querying the database for data that doesn't exist in the test database.

Is there a way to disable the data migrations? (I want to keep schema migrations, not disable migrations completely).

Or alternatively to load data from fixtures before running the data migrations?

Comment: @e4c5 This has absolutely nothing to do with the speed of tests or disabling migrations. Do people actually bother to read the question before trying to say it is a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I should notice that this solution is a dirty trick :)

I think that you should check whether your tests are running and exclude your data migrations from execution if the answer is True.
To check whether tests are running you may define your own DiscoverRunner and set a variable showing that tests are running now.

> A test runner is a class defining a run_tests() method. Django ships with a DiscoverRunner class that defines the default Django testing behavior. This class defines the run_tests() entry point, plus a selection of other methods that are used to by run_tests() to set up, execute and tear down the test suite.

For example, define TEST_RUNNER in your settings.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class MyTestSuiteRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        settings.TEST_RUN = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

TEST_RUNNER = 'project_name.test_settings.MyTestSuiteRunner'
```

Let's assume then that your have only two migrations in your app:

- 0001_initial.py
- 0002_data_migration.py

So you should check in your data_migration whether tests are running and either include or not your operations.

```
from your_app.settings import settings
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_app', '0001_initial.py'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(data_migration_method),
    ] if not settings.TEST_RUN else []
```

One more time I notice that in my opinion it's a dirty hack and it would be interesting to read how it should made in a proper way but this solution may help to solve your problem saving migration dependencies.
Note that you can also add TEST_RUNNER in your test_settings run your tests as a AR7 have been suggested.

Also check the TEST_RUNNER documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner). I hope it will help you to find better solution.

Another solution is to use django-pytest instead of standard unittest module. Pytest provides a set of useful tools for testing Django applications and projects. It also helps to disable Django migrations and create the database by inspecting all models. Just use --nomigrations flag running your tests. Read documentation for more info (https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#nomigrations-disable-django-1-7-migrations)

Answer (score 5):

I was inspired by [Disable migrations while testing](https://gist.github.com/wolever/ccc4551f39d5780c3f498b3ebc0fb9c5) and [@A. Grinenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496621/disable-data-migrations-in-django-when-creating-test-database/44528796#44528796). I did not customize TestRunner and I just checked whether `0002_data_migration.py` was called by django test.
code:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
dependencies = [
    ('backend', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(setup_data, rollback_setup, atomic=True)
] if 'test' not in sys.argv[1:] else []
```

Comment: you can skip specific migrations file by this way

Answer (score 4):

For check either test are running or not:

```
'test' in sys.argv
```

Answer (score 2):

you can run tests with `--keepdb`,

django docs:

> You can prevent the test databases from being destroyed by using the
>   test --keepdb option. This will preserve the test database between
>   runs. If the database does not exist, it will first be created. Any
>   migrations will also be applied in order to keep it up to date.

so you create a test database with valid data, and applied latest migrations, then run tests, and django won't try to create tables or run migrations while runnng tests :-)

---

note that  instead of using `keepdb` I recommend that update your data migrations functions to be able to run them on empty dataset (for example in head of your migration function check if table is empty or not, if it's empty return with a warning message)

Comment: That would be useful if I had a populated test db, but I don't.

Comment: so I think your only solution is updating your migration files and updating them as I said in the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable migrations from the `settings.py` file to speed up testing. Better create a separate settings files for the test and put the following code to disable the migrations:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
'auth': None,
'contenttypes': None,
'default': None,
'sessions': None,

'core': None,
'profiles': None,
'snippets': None,
'scaffold_templates': None,
}
```

To run the tests with the custom settings file use the following command

```
python manage.py test --settings=project.tests_settings
```

Comment: I don't actually want to disable the schema migrations, only the data migrations.